# Passing a callback from Python to C on a structure

Tags: python, c

I've been trying to pass a callback function from Python to C contained by a struct. So far I've haven't had any luck on how to pass the Python function back to C.

The C struct definition is the following:

```
typedef int (* TOUCH_CALLBACK_FUNC)(int x, int y);
typedef int (* HARDKEY_CALLBACK_FUNC)(int key);

typedef struct _rect
{
    u32 left;
    u32 top;
    u32 width;
    u32 height;  
} RECT;

typedef struct _touch_data
{
    u8  sign[16];
    u8  *file;
    RECT rect;
    u32 destWidth;
    u32 destHeight;
    u32 uiTimeOut;
    TOUCH_CALLBACK_FUNC cb;
    HARDKEY_CALLBACK_FUNC keyCb;
    void *extArg;
    void *extArg2;
} TOUCH_DATA;
```

The Python definition is the following

```
from ctypes import Structure, CFUNCTYPE, c_int32, POINTER

TOUCH_CALLBACK_FUNC = CFUNCTYPE(c_int32, POINTER(c_int32), POINTER(c_int32))
HARDKEY_CALLBACK_FUNC = CFUNCTYPE(c_int32, POINTER(c_int32))

class Rect(Structure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [('left', c_int32),
                  ('top', c_int32),
                  ('width', c_int32),
                  ('height', c_int32)]

class TouchDataStruct(Structure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [('sign', c_char * 16),
                  ('file', c_char_p),
                  ('rect', Rect),
                  ('destWidth', c_uint32),
                  ('destHeight', c_uint32),
                  ('touchCallback', TOUCH_CALLBACK_FUNC),
                  ('keyCallback', HARDKEY_CALLBACK_FUNC),
                  ('uiTimeOut', c_uint32),
                  ('extArg', c_void_p),
                  ('extArg2', c_void_p)]
```

I'm executing the following code from Python:

```
def touch_cb(x, y):
    return 0


def key_cb(key):
    return 0

data = TouchDataStruct(
    file='...'.encode('ascii'),
    rect=Rect(left=0,top=0,width=50,height=25),
    cb=TOUCH_CALLBACK_FUNC(touch_cb),
    keyCb=TOUCH_CALLBACK_FUNC(key_cb),
    destWidth=75,
    destHeight=30,
    uiTimeOut=60000
)

cwrapper.process(data)
```

The actual error is that the `size_t` of the Structure that C is receiving is 48 and the `size_t` of the actual C Structure is 64.

To receive the structure on C I'm using the following snippet:

```
PyObject *Wrapper_Process(PyObject *self, PyObject *args) {
    TOUCH_DATA *touch_data;
    size_t size;

    PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "y#", &touch_data, &size);
    if (size != sizeof(TOUCH_DATA)) {
        // Raise error here!
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance :)

**Edit 1:** Added more details on both structures and detailed the error

**Edit 2:** Forgot to convert a string to bytes

**Edit 3:** The example code had double underscore for fields and pack (which was correct on the actual code, just correcting it here)

Comment: This is supposed to work, according to the ctypes documentation.  Therefore, we need to see a _complete program_ and the _exact text_ of the error messages you are getting, or if there are no error messages, an excruciatingly detailed description of what happens when you run the program and how that differs from what you want to happen.  Leave nothing out.

Comment: Did you try taking out `__pack__ = 1`?

Comment: I just figured out what the issue was, on the actual python code on my machine, the definition of Rect was missing a underscore on the fields declaration